# Array value changes unintentionally

Tags: c++

At first line, get inputs `n` (the numbers of nodes), `m` (the numbers of edges), `start` (the start node Number) and get the undirected `m` edges/
In the end, I want to print out the dfs result. However, when I used `Node*`, it changes. I don't intend to change.

```
class Node {
private:
    int n;
    Node* next = 0;
public:
    Node(int _n) {
        n = _n;
    }
    Node() {};
    Node* getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    void setNext(Node* ptr) {
        next = ptr;
    }
};
```

Below code are the main problem.

```
Node* arr = new Node[n + 1];// use 1 to n

for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
    cin >> num1 >> num2;

    if (!arr[num1].getNext())
        arr[num1].setNext(&Node(num2));
    else {
        Node* tptr = arr[num1].getNext();
        while (tptr->getNext()) tptr = tptr->getNext();
        tptr->setNext(&Node(num2));
    }
}
```

I tried to save the adjacent Nodes(to Node 'i') in the arr[i].

Sample code is:

```
4 5 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
```

The result structure I expected was arr[1] -> 2 -> 3 -> 4, but the real outcome was arr[1]-> 2 -> 4 -> 4.

I don't understand why the value changes.

Comment: `arr[num1].setNext(&Node(num2));` is wrong as you store pointer of temporary object.

Comment: `arr[i]` seems not initialized.

Comment: I tried both "Node temp = Node(num2) or Node* temp = &Node(num2)". but it doen't work. The value changes. I think the memory address doesn't change what ever i do.

Comment: `Node* temp = &Node(num2)` has same issue. For `Node temp = Node(num2)`, `temp` should outlive `arr[num1]`.
You probably want `arr[num1].setNext(&arr[num2])`.

Comment: `Node* arr = new Node[n + 1];` -- generally speaking, owning pointers are considered a bad thing, and obsolete since C++11 brought us [unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [weak_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr).

Comment: Indexing starts at 0. Trying to deny this simple fact will bring you nothing but troubles.